# Keeping my prompt content private

Tags: chatgpt

I am using ChatGPT and friends a lot for work and professional info. They work amazingly well. However I have an application in mind where I can't upload my prompt content to the cloud because it is confidential and private.

I tried PrivatGPT (https://github.com/imartinez/privateGPT) and it didn't work. I spent only about 30 minutes messing with it. It seems to have the right idea but when I typed in a prompt, after quite a while computing, it printed out gibberisg, that is random characters. I think I read that someone else had that experience

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just prompts that you are looking to make, GPT4ALL with the right model may work for you.

https://gpt4all.io/index.html

You can download the client at the link above, and then select and download various models. Play with the models until you find one that works best on your hardware.

Comment: I am on a Mac and have successfully installed gpt4all. I have designated a directory for local docs and I think have it set up correctly, including the checkbox. But I cannot tell whether it’s doing anything. It looks to me like it has not ingested the files I supplied. Any hints?